# chroot + execvp + bash

Tags: bash, chroot

**Update**

*Got it! See my solution (fifth comment)*

Here is my problem:

I have created a small binary called "jail" and in /etc/password I have made it the default shell for a test user.

Here is the -- simplified -- source code:

```
#define HOME "/home/user"
#define SHELL "/bin/bash"
...
if(chdir(HOME) || chroot(HOME)) return -1;
...
char *shellargv[] = { SHELL, "-login", "-rcfile", "/bin/myscript", 0 };
execvp(SHELL, shellargv);
```

Well, no matter how hard I try, it seems that, when my test user logs in, */bin/myscript* will never be sourced. Similarly, if I drop a `.bashrc` file in user's home directory, it will be ignored as well.

Why would bash snob these guys?

--

Some precisions, not necessarily relevant, but to clear out some of the points made in the comments:

- The 'jail' binary is actually suid, thus allowing it to chroot() successfully.
- I have used 'ln' to make the appropriate binaries available - my jail cell is nicely padded :)
- The issue does not seem to be with chrooting the user...something else is remiss.

Answer (score 4):

As Jason C says, the exec'ed shell isn't interactive.

His solution will force the shell to be interactive if it accepts `-i` to mean that (and bash does):

```
char *shellargv[] = { SHELL, "-i", "-login", ... };
execvp(SHELL, shellargv);
```

I want to add, though, that traditionally a shell will act as a login shell if `ARGV[0]` begins with a dash.

```
char *shellargv[] = {"-"SHELL, "-i", ...};
execvp(SHELL, shellargv);
```

Usually, though, Bash will autodetect whether it should run interactively or not.  Its failure to in your case may be because of missing `/dev/*` nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The shell isn't interactive.  Try adding -i to the list of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I can identify with wanting to do this yourself, but if you haven't already, check out [jail chroot project](http://www.jmcresearch.com/projects/jail/) and [jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/index.html#intro) for some drop in tools to create a jail shell.

Answer (score 1):

By the time your user is logging in and their shell tries to source this file, it's running under their UID. The `chroot()` system call is only usable by root -- you'll need to be cleverer than this.

Also, chrooting to a user's home directory will make their shell useless, as (unless they have a lot of stuff in there) they won't have access to any binaries. Useful things like `ls`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, guys,

I figured it out:

I forgot to **setuid()/setgid()**, chroot(), setuid()/setgid() back, then pass a proper environment using execve()

Oh, and, if I pass no argument to bash, it will source *~/.bashrc*

If I pass "-l" if will source */etc/profile*

Cheers!

Comment: Ah, I had (falsely) assumed that either your chroot had everything in the same places as the typical system, or you were fixing up the environment first.  Lacking the setuid/gid back shouldn't break this (although it would eliminate the security benefit to chrooting).